# How to recognize a monomial quiver algebra

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory, quiver

Given a basic split finite dimensional algebra $A$ over a field K, A is isomorphic to $KQ/I_1$, for some quiver Q and a minimal(meaning it is generated by relations $x_i$, such that no relation is implied by any other) admissible ideal $I_1$. Now A can be isomorphic to $KQ/I_2$ for a different minimal admissible ideal $I_2$. 
There are examples where $I_1$ is monomial but $I_2$ is not.

Question: Given $A=KQ/I_1$, how can one know wheter there exists a monomial minimal admissible ideal $I_2$ such that $A \cong K/I_2$?

For example, I think if $A$ is a selfinjective algebra then this can never happen expect when $A$ is a Nakayama algebra.

Comment: Not when i assume that the algebra is basic and split I think.

Comment: what is your definition of split? an algebra A over K is split for me if A/J is isomorphic to a product of matrix rings over the field K.